# How do I delete line break in PDF text extraction in Python?

Tags: python, pymupdf

I used PyMuPDF to get the text in the PDF, here is my code

```
import fitz

pdf_document = "KRIP.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(pdf_document)

page1 = doc.loadPage(0)
page1text = page1.get_text()
print("Text from PDF: ", page1text)
```

the output should be

```
KRIPTOGRAFI
```

but it turns out

```
KRIPTOGRAFI
```

there is a line break after the word "KRIPTOGRAFI".
Is there any way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the blanks at the end. The function [`strip()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) does that for you.

Your new code would be:

```
import fitz

pdf_document = "KRIP.pdf"
doc = fitz.open(pdf_document)

page1 = doc.loadPage(0)
page1text = page1.get_text().strip()
print("Text from PDF: ", page1text)
```

Comment: @brianK If I helped then you can choose the `tick` sign under the question score. Glad it worked!